# Count the total number of duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio and I'm looking for a query to be able to count the total number of duplicate rows from a query.

At present I have a query that outputs driver names and vehicle registrations, for any driver that hasn't submitted a vehicle check sheet for 2 consecutive weeks. But I'm now trying to create a second query that gives me the total count of the duplicate rows.

My current query below that outputs the driver names and vehicle registrations, for checksheets that haven't been submitted in 2 consecutive weeks:

```
SELECT DriverName, EngineerVehicleReg_FK
FROM tblPDAForms a WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN tblGeneralVehicleInformation b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.EngineerVehicleReg_FK = b.EngineerVehicleReg  
JOIN tblVehicleStatus c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.VehicleStatus_IDFK = c.VehicleStatus_ID  
JOIN tblDrivers d WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.AggoraAgent_IDFK = d.AggoraAgent_IDFK  
WHERE PDAFormLocation IS NULL  
AND VehicleStatus_ID IN ('1','5','7')
AND Location_IDFK NOT IN ('7','13') AND EndDate IS NULL  
AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-21,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())
GROUP BY DriverName, EngineerVehicleReg_FK
HAVING 
(COUNT(DriverName) > 1) AND
(COUNT(EngineerVehicleReg_FK) > 1)
order by DriverName
```

Below is the output:

```
|DriverName|EngineerVehicleReg_FK|
|----------|---------------------|
|Ian       |PK19 OVB             |
|Jack      |BX69 TXG             |
|John      |FP22 HTE             |
|Leigh     |FG72 ZTN             |
|Noel      |FP22 HWW             |
|Ross      |FL23 RYK             |
|Tom       |FP22 HWV             |
```

I now need a second query that will provide the count these records. So in this example I'd like to be able to run a query and it just show a count of 7.

I have tried a few things and the closest I got was the below:

```
SELECT COUNT(EngineerVehicleReg_FK) AS Reg  
FROM tblPDAForms pda WITH (NOLOCK)  
JOIN tblGeneralVehicleInformation gv WITH (NOLOCK) ON pda.EngineerVehicleReg_FK = gv.EngineerVehicleReg  
JOIN tblVehicleStatus v WITH (NOLOCK) ON gv.VehicleStatus_IDFK = v.VehicleStatus_ID  
JOIN tblDrivers d WITH (NOLOCK) ON pda.AggoraAgent_IDFK = d.AggoraAgent_IDFK  
WHERE PDAFormLocation IS NULL  
AND VehicleStatus_ID IN ('1','5','7') AND Location_IDFK NOT IN ('7','13') AND EndDate IS NULL  
AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-21,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())
GROUP BY EngineerVehicleReg_FK
HAVING COUNT(EngineerVehicleReg_FK) > 1
```

Which outputs a count but of how many times each record shows:

```
|Reg|
|---|
|2  |
|2  |
|2  |
|2  |
|2  |
|2  |
|2  |
```

This isn't the output I wanted, as I was trying to get the below output:

```
|Reg|
|---|
|7  |
```

Any help and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

-----RESOLVED-----
This has been resolved using the suggestion of making my first query into a sub query.

Comment: Put your results into a temp table and then select count(*)

Comment: Ps don't use nolock everywhere unless you fully understand implications of doing so. It's rare that you would really need/want to do so.

Comment: Or use your original query in a CTE and select count(*) from it.

Comment: @DaleK, the temp table is a better solution, as the base query is executed once.

Comment: @RomEh can't really define better without knowing OPs context... hence just throwing ideas out there in the hope that they clarify.

Comment: By "second query " you mean a query that will run second? You can just do `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` after the initial `SELECT` to see how many rows it was - or you will be running this entirely independently and separately from the "first" query?

Comment: My apologies, I could I have perhaps explained that a bit better. The 2nd "count" query that I'm trying to create is something to be run entirely independently and separately to the "first" query.

So i'm not sure if using the temp table's will work in this scenario.

Comment: You need to wrap the first query (the one that gives you the list of duplicate records) as a subquery, and then apply the `COUNT` function to the result of that subquery or you can use Common Table Expression (CTE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two `select` clauses because you need to aggregate twice effectively, first is to find which have duplicate entries and the second is to count the results.

From this point the simplest solution is to wrap your query making it a [derived table](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/05/t-sql-queries/table-expressions-part-2):

```
SELECT COUNT(Reg) as Reg FROM (<your query here>) z;
```

Comment: The technical term is a sub-query.

Comment: No, it is "subquery" at least in SQL Server and it contains a select statement. Nothing I said was incorrect, unless you are saying the solution won't work.There are other options such as the temp table you suggested which still involves two select statements, first to create the table and second to read from it.

Comment: And a FROM clause sub-query is called _derived table_.

Comment: I don't care how you spell it - I was commenting on your first sentence: use 2 select statements - whereas i think it's clearer to say use a subquery. Nothing wrong with your solution.

Comment: Fundamentally it's a select statement, regardless of the technical term I'm trying to explain that you need to count/aggregate twice which means you need to write select twice. I can remove the word statement if that means it better?

Comment: Single statement containing the `SELECT` keyword/clause twice

Comment: @Jegsar Thank you very much, this has worked perfectly and given me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the first query (the one that gives you the list of duplicate records) as a subquery, and then apply the `COUNT` function to the result of that subquery or you can use Common Table Expression (CTE)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalDuplicateCount
FROM (
    SELECT DriverName, EngineerVehicleReg_FK
    FROM tblPDAForms a WITH (NOLOCK) 
    JOIN tblGeneralVehicleInformation b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.EngineerVehicleReg_FK = b.EngineerVehicleReg  
    JOIN tblVehicleStatus c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.VehicleStatus_IDFK = c.VehicleStatus_ID  
    JOIN tblDrivers d WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.AggoraAgent_IDFK = d.AggoraAgent_IDFK  
    WHERE PDAFormLocation IS NULL  
    AND VehicleStatus_ID IN ('1','5','7')
    AND Location_IDFK NOT IN ('7','13') AND EndDate IS NULL  
    AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -21, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY DriverName, EngineerVehicleReg_FK
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS DuplicateRecords
```

Using Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
;WITH DuplicateRecordsCTE AS (
    SELECT DriverName, EngineerVehicleReg_FK
    FROM tblPDAForms a WITH (NOLOCK) 
    JOIN tblGeneralVehicleInformation b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.EngineerVehicleReg_FK = b.EngineerVehicleReg  
    JOIN tblVehicleStatus c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.VehicleStatus_IDFK = c.VehicleStatus_ID  
    JOIN tblDrivers d WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.AggoraAgent_IDFK = d.AggoraAgent_IDFK  
    WHERE PDAFormLocation IS NULL  
    AND VehicleStatus_ID IN ('1','5','7')
    AND Location_IDFK NOT IN ('7','13') AND EndDate IS NULL  
    AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -21, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY DriverName, EngineerVehicleReg_FK
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalDuplicateCount
FROM DuplicateRecordsCTE;
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the subquery method and that has worked perfectly.